# Flux: how to handle multiple async requests

Tags: asynchronous, reactjs, flux

I'm writing a simple application using flux design principles to get a better understanding of the underlying mechanics.  In order to deliver an enhanced experience, user changes are recorded immediately to the local store, therefore updating the interface with zero latency. At the same time, an async request is dispatched to the server; in the event of server failure, the local store is reloaded from the server.

However, I'm unsure how best to handle a scenario in which, due to a slow server response, there are multiple async requests pending.  Dealing with a failure seems much more complex in such a scenario.  For example, assume there are three pending async requests (one for each state mutating user interaction).  The first succeeds, but the second fails.  Should I cancel the third request?  How do I just rollback the changes from the second request but not the third.

I want to avoid this kind of complexity if at all possible. Does flux provide a mechanism to deal with such scenarios?  I realize that I can lock the UI while an async request is pending to prevent multiple requests from queuing, but I'm loathe to introduce the degraded user experience of such an approach.

Edit: 
Some have fairly questioned whether the problem of multiple async calls is specific to flux.  What I failed to mention is that my concern is specific to the [guidance](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/07/30/flux-actions-and-the-dispatcher.html) that stores/dispatchers only execute synchronous code.

Comment: In addition to being a bad user experienec, blocking the UI in order to prevent the scenario where multiple async operations occur simultaneously is a bad code smell.

It's a form of coupling; you make assumptions about the view from outside the view (i.e. in an Action Creator).

Answer (score 0):

Well, are asking to different questions. First is how to manage history of changes to the state and the second is how to handle failure.

**how to manage history of changes to the state**

Facebook doesn't provide solution for such problem. Flux is just a architecture, not a library or framework. But it is an old problem which have been solved many times. Basic approach is, that state can be changed only by applying operations to the state, and there is  a possibility to cancel or undo each operation . You can use [Rx-Flux](https://github.com/fdecampredon/rx-flux) (but it is not completed yet) for this or some undo/redo library might provide required functionality.

**How to handle failure**

There can't be a generic solution for such generic example. In some cases you can simply swallow failed operation and forget about it, in some you will have to retry operation until it succeeds, in some cases you will have to ask user to perform some action in order for problem to be resolved. For some fast paced game there will be one solution, for internet banking we will have another.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds to me that the question is not about the flux architecture but rather the implementation on the async calls.

Assume the current implementation you're triggering the async calls once you get the user interaction state changes. When you triggered the AJAX, it is only possible to cancel it on the client side, which means you call the `abort` to turn off the response's listener. But now on the server side the third request will still proceed.

Unless you implement the way that >> each user interaction state changes will be store a queue (could be an array)..and then you triggered the AJAX call one after another.

would understand/explain better if you could provide any code snippets :)